# AWS Lambda, Puppeteer Lambda, Task timed out, getBrowser()

Tags: aws-lambda, puppeteer

I am trying to run Lambda function using puppeteer-lambda.
1. I installed it with 'npm install puppeteer-lambda'.
2. I uploaded chrome version on separate S3 bucket than the function.
3. In proccess.env I set CHROME_BUCKET and CHROME_KEY.
4. TimeOut is set to 5mins.

It works perfectly till it comes to pupeeteerLambda.getBroser();

```
async function parseEngine(commandArray, inPage, iterator, parameters) {
try {
    let page = inPage;
    if (!page) {
        console.log('getting browser');
        const browser = await puppeteerLambda.getBrowser({ headless: true, slowMo: 100,  args: ['--no-sandbox', '--disable-setuid-sandbox', '--start-fullscreen', '--window-size=1413,749']});
        console.log('opening page');
        page = await browser.newPage();

        await page.setViewport({ width: 1413, height: 749 });
        page.setUserAgent(config.USER_AGENT);
    }
 etc..
```

...........

I tried to console.log everything.

Does anyone have idea what can fix this ?

Thanks.

Comment: I could do with some more information: using your logging, can you tell if the lambda get's the last line of the function, or if it gets stuck waiting mid-function? I'm particularly suspicious that you may not be doing `await browser.close();`, which means your lambda is just waiting for your browser to somehow close itself.

Comment: It is not passing getBrowser(). I am trying to figure out why. although I don't have await browser.close() on purpose coz of some testing. Do you think that it is not going to page = await browser.newPage(); because of that?

Comment: If you don't close the browser it's possible the lambda won't terminate because it's waiting for the event loop to finish (see context.callbackWaitsForEmptyEventLoop) however in this case it looks like getBrowser is what's taking the while. I would check that you have permissions (S3:getObject) on the lambda and up the memory to the maximum (Chrome isn't light!)

Comment: I have permission on S3 bucket that I created. Memory is set to max and I tried with await browser.close(); .. same thing. Locally is running perfectly.

Comment: Also, maybe Node 8.1 is causing the problem?

Comment: I doubt it's the node version, given their async/await example. Looking at the code, setting DEBUG to 1 in the environment might hint at what's up

Comment: DEBUG prints 'setup s3 chrome'..
const setupS3Chrome = () => {
    return new Promise((resolve, reject) => {
        const params = {
            Bucket: config.remoteChromeS3Bucket,
            Key: config.remoteChromeS3Key,
        };
        s3.getObject(params)
            .createReadStream()
            .on('error', (err) => {
                reject(err);
            })
            .pipe(tar.x({
                C: config.setupChromePath,
            }))